# Best practice to tell inherited methods from class's own method

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, refactoring

Im on a project where i have a database class that extends ADODB_base class - **My goal is to replace ADODB_class with an ad-hoc database wrapper layer class**.

The class has ~200 methods; what can be a good practice to identify the methods it inherit from ADODB_class (that i have to recreate with same name/args in the custom wrapper in order to avoid big headcaches in the refactoring) and it's *own* methods?

**EDIT:** a sample code:

```
class Postgres extends ADODB_base{
    //[...]
    // This method exist in Postgres class but not in ADODB_base,
    // let's say this is a Postgres own method.
    public function do_something()
    {
        //[...]
        // query() method belongs to ADODB_base class, so i need to create it
        // in my wrapper too, keeping the name and the args.
        $this->query([...]);
    }
    //[...]
}
```

My goal is to find the best practices to tell that `do_something()` belongs to `Postgres`, while `query()` belongs to `ADODB_base`, **without change all the code that use `Postgres` class.**

Will be lovely to identify even attributes..

Comment: I still dont understand what that wrapper is going to do or why it has to have methods of ADODB_Base when the Postgres class will make those available anyways because it inherits from it.

Comment: Becose i have to completely remove ADODB class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is some approaches, none of which I would feel comfortable to name Best Practise:

#### Example classes

```
class A
{
    public function fn() {}
}
class B extends A 
{
    public function foo() {}
}
```

The Reflection API can pretty much identify every aspect of your classes. However, this comes at a performance impact due to the heavy analysis process required to provide this information. Somewhat faster alternatives are the Class/Object functions. However, the information possible to gather is much more limited than what Reflection provides.

#### Using [Reflection API](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to get class where a method was defined

```
$reflector = new ReflectionMethod('B', 'fn');
echo $reflector->getDeclaringClass()->getName(); // A
$reflector = new ReflectionMethod('B', 'foo');
echo $reflector->getDeclaringClass()->getName(); // B
```

#### Using [Class/Object function](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ref.classobj.php) to check if method exists in parent

```
var_dump(method_exists(get_parent_class('B'), 'fn'));  // TRUE
var_dump(method_exists(get_parent_class('B'), 'foo')); // FALSE
```

#### Using Class/Object function to list all parent methods

```
print_r(get_class_methods(get_parent_class('B')));
```

Live Demo for all of the above: http://codepad.org/YWrKGNzm

---

#### Using a Decorator

If this is for some sort of Decorator pattern, you can also use the magic `__call` methods to intercept and delegate any calls to methods not in the decorator to the decorated instance, e.g.

```
class Decorator 
{    
    public function __construct($instance)
    {
        $this->decoratedInstance = $instance;
    }
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(
            array($this->decoratedInstance, $method), 
            $args
        );    
    }
}
```

Note that all magic method can have a severe performance impact on your application and you want to benchmark the solution to see if it's tolerable in your setup.

---

#### Further readings

For additional ideas, have a look at other [Structural Design Patterns](http://sourcemaking.com/structural_patterns)

Comment: And decorator can't be used in this case, because code of decorated class will be removed by author.

Comment: @OZ the OP isnt very clear about what he's really trying to achieve, so I wouldnt rule out the decorator.

Comment: Gordon, he just want to remove 1 class from his code. But this class is "parent" for other class, so he have to write the replacement.

Comment: @OZ what for does he need to know if the class belongs to ADODB then? What is the wrapper for he is talking about? If this is some sort of adapter than can bind to several db backends, it makes no sense to give it the same methods as ADODB because it wont be an abstraction then.